# MySQL SELECT only non alpha numbers

Tags: mysql

I have a VARCHAR type field that can contains both numeric (222) or alpha-number (CPO13) values.

I want to select only values that are numeric?  I see in example how to choose non-numeric but I want to filter out those with letters of the alphabet?

Comment: If you know how to choose non-numeric values, just add `NOT` to the `WHERE` condition and it will filter them out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using a Regular Expression that filters for values with both numeric and alphabetical characters . For example:

```
SELECT * FROM DATA WHERE FIELD REGEXP NOT '[A-z].[0-9]';
```

mySQL allows you to use regular expression as a filter !

This should select out for values like CPO13. If you want to practice regular expressions this is a great website to test whether you have the right regex. https://regex101.com/

Hope this helps !

Comment: You need to put the regexp in quotes.

Comment: Yes, sorry I just edited it, i forgot to include them.  Thank You

Comment: The question also says he wants to exclude alphabetic, not return them.